# Ramdisk that persists old files

Tags: linux, rsync, cache, ramdisk, temporary-files

I've got a program that writes a file to disk, then another processes it. Usually this happens within a second or so, so the file is nearly temporary. To avoid disk IO, I write to /dev/shm. However, if the second process stops working or gets on behind, I don't want to lose *all* data in case of system crash/reboot.

I want a setup that'll copy files older than X seconds to the hard disk (not SSD.

Now I've seen [EPRD](http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/?p=699), but it works on a block level. So it won't have the file semantics or safety I desire. Same for bcache, as far as I can tell. (Plus bcache is aimed at SSD type performance, so it probably isn't best to use it with HDDs.)

I want there to be zero disk IO in normal condition, then simply copying the files after a certain age. Can I use a standard filesystem and set some write-back caching and get this functionality? Or is this something for a cronjob and rsync?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on in-memory files but could live with in-memory data of the files and don't fear developing your current codes a bit, you can use redis. http://redis.io/

It is a very very very simple in-memory key-value database manager that persists data to disk after given time intervals, and it has bindings to all reasonable languages in addition to a handy cli tool.

What you would have to do is:

- set the persistence interval of redis to a value you think is safe enough to store what's waiting for too long but long enough not to store data that appears and disappears in time,
- write the data into redis in process A instead of writing it into into a file,
- read the data from redis in process A,
- delete the data

In case redis or the OS crashes, next time redis is started, the data persisted will be automatically read in waiting for processing.

Comment: The existing program reads files and isn't changeable.